# Eliminación recursiva de filas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo en la DB una tabla de "Carpetas" con una columna que referencia a la misma tabla:

```
id --> pk
nombre_carpeta --> VARCHAR();
id_carpeta_padre --> id de la carpeta padre
```

No pude hacerla foránea y aplicarle un `ON DELETE CASCADE` (que sería la solución más óptima, clara y abstracta posible) ya que SQL SERVER no me permite por un tema de ciclos. Mi problema reside en que cuando quiero eliminar un carpeta con id = `X` quiero eliminar todos los sub directorios que cuelgan de él, es decir, las carpetas que tengan id_carpeta_padre = `X` y sus subdirectorios, y así recursivamente.

¿Hay alguna forma?

Comment: Hay un nivel de "anidamiento" máximo? Lo pregunto por que cualquier solución en SQL Server recursiva tiene un límite.

Comment: Nono, solo recibo el nivel de la carpeta a eliminar. Desde ahi hay que sacar todos sus sub directorios

Comment: Ok, me imaginaba, ahí escribí una respuesta, espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es una prueba de concepto de como eliminar un árbol de datos con un anidamiento variable. La tabla `@Prueba` es la tabla de dónde vamos a eliminar y que tiene un Id y un IdPadre, el registro inicial del árbol tiene un IdPadre = NULL. En este ejemplo quiero borrar una rama de 6 niveles, aquella cuyo Id = 1. La tabla @ToDelete va a tener los @Id que luego deberemos eliminar. Debería funcionar también arrancando de ramas intermedias y por supuesto debe borrar las ramas completas.

```
DECLARE @Prueba TABLE (
    Id          INT,
    IdPadre     INT
)

DECLARE @ToDelete TABLE (
    Id          INT,
    IdPadre     INT
)

INSERT INTO @Prueba(Id, IdPadre)
SELECT 1, NULL  UNION
SELECT 2, NULL  UNION
SELECT 3, 1  UNION
SELECT 4, 3  UNION
SELECT 5, 4  UNION
SELECT 6, 5  UNION
SELECT 7, 6  UNION
SELECT 8, 2


DECLARE @IdToDelete     INT
DECLARE @Rows       INT
SELECT  @IdToDelete = 1

INSERT INTO @ToDelete (Id, IdPadre)
SELECT  Id, IdPadre
    FROM    @Prueba
    WHERE   ID = @IdToDelete

SELECT  @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE   @Rows <> 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @ToDelete (Id, IdPadre)
    SELECT  P2.Id, 
        P2.IdPadre
        FROM    @ToDelete P1
        INNER JOIN @Prueba P2
            ON P2.IdPadre = P1.Id
        LEFT JOIN @ToDelete P3
            ON P3.Id = P2.Id

        WHERE P3.ID IS NULL


    SELECT  @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

END

SELECT  *
    FROM @ToDelete
```

Comment: Gracias! Mañana la pruebo y aviso!